# Fade out UIView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uikit, fade

I have an UIView here that I'd like to partially fade the bottom of. Basically I want the alpha value to decrease the further down on the UIView we go. So the top of the UIView is completely visible, while the bottom part has an alpha value of 0.

Anybody got any suggestion as to how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CALayer` has a property called `mask`, which is designed for doing precisely this sort of effect. If you assign another CALayer to the mask (one that has no superlayer), the alpha channel of that second CALayer is used when compositing the first CALayer.

Be careful, though, as using the mask property has a significant performance hit.

Comment: So how would I use the mask to change the alpha value of the bottom of the CALayer?

Comment: Create an image containing a gradient on the alpha channel. Assign this image as the contents property of a brand new layer with the same size as the one you want to fade out. Then assign this new layer as the mask of your original layer.

Comment: This would fade out whatever is behind this view though, wouldn't it? Basically what I'm trying to create here is a reflection below an UIImageView. I already have the reflection in place, but I want it to fade away the further down I go. And the image is usually a transparent png, so adding a gradient would mean the background would fade away as well.

Comment: Adding a mask to a layer will only affect that layer and its sublayers. It won't affect anything below it.